# change page width color background

Tags: html, css

I'm pursuing HTML for non traditional reasons.  I think that it provides a more suitable canvass than MS Word or LaTeX in academic papers as it affords the author better means of communication.  I am attempting to write a format that can be used for academic papers that conformas to traditional APA 6 guidelines.

I want to use either the index.html file or the style.css (I don't know which is more appropriate) to make the page look like an 8.5 width paper (exact size is not important) rather than the full width on a light grey background.  This is done in the wordpress twenty twelve theme as seen here:

[image]

How can I replicate this feel by altering the index.html file (as seen below) or perhaps I need to add something to the style.css file?  Specifically how can I ass a colored background with a "page" on top?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.
  </body>
</html>
```

I tried stealing from twenty twelve but couldn't understand because the files are php and I don't know what is doing what in the style.scc file.

Comment: IT would be infinitely helpful if the downvoters stated why.  How can I (a newbie to the html language and your community on SO) understand the language or the culture of your community if you don't tell me what I did wrong.  I post frequently in the R part of SO and if I downvote I tell the person why so they can fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick example...the specific rules are easy enough to change, but should give you an idea. Basically, you set a width smaller than 100% on a child element of the body (`div.container`). Then, set the `margin-left` and `margin-right` values to `auto` in order to get it to center horizontally. The `height:400px` and the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` set to `1em` are arbitrary values. The content of your page just needs to be built inside the `div.container` element...your faux page.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXdY8/

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #efefef;
}
.container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 400px;
    margin: 1em auto;
    background: #FFF;
}
.container p {
    padding: 1em;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
   <div class="container">
      <p>Four score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal. Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battle-field of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field, as a final resting place for those who here gave their lives that that nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this.</p>
   </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.  That gives me something to work with and insight into the magic

Comment: You may want to add some styles that allow more flexibility.  `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }` combined with `.container { width: 1140px; max-width: 100%; min-height: 90%; }` will cause your page to look nice on mobile devices and desktops.  It'll also look more like paper because it'll take at least 90% of the screen height (on any device).